# How to change the background color of input tag only for specific values

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, onmouseover

I want to set `background-color: #F5B7B1` property of an `input` tag, but only for values ​​less than `1` and more than a `1000`. Why does this code not working?

```js
    function f() {
    var input=this.getElementById("number_input").value;
    if (input<1||input>1000)this.getElementById("number_input").style.backgroundColor=#F5B7B1;}
```

```html
<form class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-pale-green central">
    <h2>Desired Input</h2>

    <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" onmouseover="f()" type="number" id="number_input" placeholder="Enter a number between 1 and 1000!"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` inside function refers to the *window* object which does not have `getElementById()`

You should pass `this` to the function so that you can refer that inside the function. I also think using `oninput` event is more meaningful here.

Also note that the colour coded value is string, you have to wrap that with quotes (`"#F5B7B1"` or `'#F5B7B1'`).

```js
function f(el) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(this.constructor.name) //Window
  var input=el.value;
  if (input<1 || input>1000)el.style.backgroundColor="#F5B7B1";
  else{
    el.style.backgroundColor="lightgray";
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-pale-green central">
  <h2>Desired Input</h2>

  <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" oninput="f(this)" type="number" id="number_input" placeholder="Enter a number between 1 and 1000!"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: The solution also changed `backgroundColor=#F5B7B1` to `backgroundColor="#F5B7B1"` Is it worth adding a note about that (values vs. fields, etc) to help @Zahra?

Comment: @andrewjames, I missed that point to mention, updated the answer, thanks:)